# MapiSendMail for .Net app running in admin mode

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, mapi

Our application is running in ADMIN Mode (Run as Administrator) in Windows 7 64 bit machine. Application internally calls MAPISendMail (IN C#) which will open up Outlook Message Box 
and user will have to click Send Button to send mail. This works fine if user has opened his Outlook in ADMIN mode , but if Outlook client is running in standard user mode, Outlook Message Box is not getting opened.

Please let me know how can our application running in Admin mode can call an API which will send a mail from outlook which is already running in Standard Mode?. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

> Our application is running in ADMIN Mode (Run as Administrator)

Why do you need to run the application as an administrator?

You can read about different integrity levels in the [What is the Windows Integrity Mechanism?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625957.aspx) article.

As a workaround you may try to use the [mailto:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) command instead. For example:

```
  Process.Run("mailto:someone@example.com");
```